# how to fix scrolling issue in openui5 Dialog in iphone device?

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.ui.commons.Dialog() in openui5 which contains image with scrolling.
it is working fine in desktop and android devices but its not working in iphone.
In iphone also scrolling is there but when i click on scrollbar it is working but when i am trying to swipe the image by touch its not working.

```
function openDialog() {
    var oImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image("i1");
    oImage.setSrc("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/A6aRkhlqWuE/maxresdefault.jpg");
    oImage.setWidth("500px");
    oImage.setHeight("300px");

    var oDialog1 = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog();
    oDialog1.setWidth("250px");
    oDialog1.setTitle("My first Dialog");
    var oText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World!"});
    oDialog1.addContent(oImage);
    oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "OK", press:function(){oDialog1.close();}}));
    oDialog1.open();
};
```

here my jsbin [code.](http://jsbin.com/mewaco/edit?html,output)
 How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make an SAPUI5 application work properly on a mobile device, you should use controls from the sap.m library such as:

- sap.m.Image
- sap.m.Button
- sap.m.Dialog
- etc

Using the desktop components for a mobile app will lead to a deteriorated user-experience, such as the one your are now experiencing.